# nth-child with mod (or modulo) operator

Tags: css, css-selectors, modulo

Is it possible to use the `nth-child` with modulo? I know you can specify a formula, such as

```
nth-child(4n+2)
```

But I can't seem to find if there's a modulo operator. I've tried the following examples below, and none seem to work:

```
nth-child(n%7)
nth-child(n % 7)
nth-child(n mod 7)
```

Comment: Related: https://joeyhoer.com/advanced-nth-child-selectors

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, [`:nth-child()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) only supports addition, subtraction and [coefficient multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient).

I gather you're trying to pick up the first 6 elements (as `n mod 7` for any positive integer `n` only gives you `0` to `6`). For that, you can use this formula instead:

```
:nth-child(-n+6)
```

By negating `n`, element counting is done backwards starting from zero, so these elements will be selected:

```
 0 + 6 = 6
-1 + 6 = 5
-2 + 6 = 4
-3 + 6 = 3
-4 + 6 = 2
-5 + 6 = 1
...
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/Dh3T8)

Comment: You're close, [nth-child uses a `1` based index](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo), not `0`. You want `-n + 7`.

Comment: @zzzzBov: No, it indexes `n` from zero. "The `:nth-child(an+b)` pseudo-class notation represents an element that has `an`+`b`-1 siblings **before** it in the document tree, for any positive integer or zero value of `n`" It only states that the first child has an index of 1, which isn't related to the indexing of `n`.

Comment: I stand corrected. Good catch; I remembered the elements being a 1-based index and assumed the n index was the same without re-reading the docs.

Comment: Looks like the functionality I'm looking for doesn't exist. This answers my question, however. Thank you!

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59206065/586030

Answer (score 41):

If you want to use `nth-child` with modulo `k`, just specify:

```
nth-child(kn)
```

For example, if you want to specify style for *3, 6, 9, ..* elements, just specify (`k` = 3), and use:

```
nth-child(3n)
```

You can also specify an offset:

```
nth-child(kn+offset)
```

Answer (score 10):

I know this topic is very old, but here's the answer that's close enough to modulo operator:

```
:not(:nth-child(7n))
```

This will select elements 1-6, 8-13 and so on...

```
:nth-child(an)
```

The code above will select elements divisible by "a" so adding :not() selector forces CSS to select elements not divisible by "a".

Comment: I hadn't considered that the asker might have meant `n mod 7` to match any elements where n is not divisible by 7. This looks closer to what the original question was asking than my answer, although we'll still have to get confirmation from the asker.

Answer (score 7):

I know this topic is very old, but here's the answer:

```
    .parent :nth-child(4n):nth-last-child(2) ~ *,
    .parent :nth-child(4n):nth-last-child(3) ~ *,
    .parent :nth-child(4n):nth-last-child(4) ~ * {
        color: gold;
    }
```

This selector targets all children who are after the last child in the last full set of grouped children denoted by your nth-child formula.

Comment: This just solved a complex problem for me, thanks! I used it to hide extra images at the end of a randomized gallery that needed to have perfectly filled columns and no "stragglers" (balanced counts were more important than showing every image).

This problem arose because the number of columns changed at different browser sizes, which meant that common multiples of gallery items to match evenly required more precision than the system could guarantee. When combined with media queries, the gallery now looks clean at 3, 4, and 5 columns, regardless of how many images are in the gallery.

Comment: I found [this well written article](https://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css/) explaining the technique behind this, which helped me to understand what's actually going on.
My specific problem was slightly different: I needed to select all elements in the last row of a gallery. [This article](https://dockyard.com/blog/2019/04/16/css-selectors-for-the-entire-last-row-of-a-dynamic-grid) offers the solution for this variation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want modulous with `n=2` than you can use even or odd.

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```