# CSS pick a random color from array

Tags: html, css

Is there is a way in CSS to make it pick a random font color from an array? I know I can do this with server side or javascript, but I am wondering if there is pure CSS way to do this.

Comment: You can do it with Javascript, but not just CSS. Are you okay with a Javascript answer?

Comment: No you can't. For starters, there is no such thing as `array` in CSS.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is not possible in CSS, which is firmly deterministic. You could do this with client-side JavaScript, though:

```
var colors = ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff'];
var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
document.getElementById('title').style.color = random_color;
```

If you're using jQuery, the last line could become

```
$('#title').css('color', random_color);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I was looking for a pure CSS way. Seems like it is not possible purely with CSS.

Comment: you should prolly mark [explosion pills](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14984994/766570) answer as the correct one.. it doesn't makes sense that the incorrect answer (by you own admission) get more votes than the correct one

Comment: @abbood Explosion Pills's answer is interesting, but: "only ever supported by IE7 and below". It's not a realistic way to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using them for IE7 and below to begin with

Answer (score 64):

CSS expressions (allowing for dynamic script content via CSS) were abominations cast in the bowels of the hell of inefficiency alongside Web Forms, only ever supported by IE7  and below.  But since you asked.

```
<style>
blink marquee {
   color: expression("rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
      + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ","
      + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ")");
}
</style>
<blink>
   <marquee>
      color me beautiful
   </marquee>
</blink>
```

Comment: ok is it just me or are people's votes for this question are totallay random? this *is* the correct answer

Comment: @abbood How is this the correct answer if this only works in IE7 and below?

Comment: That's an accurate description

Comment: I can't really do it with this snippet. <marquee> will lead my Text to float from right to left, but this will also happen without any stylesheet. And there doesn't appear any color...

Comment: The marquee was ironic. I can't believe marquees still work.

Answer (score 4):

Simple in JavaScript with JQuery.

You could do something like:

```
var hexArray = ['#hexVal','#hexVal','#hexval', '#hexval']
var randomColor = hexArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * hexArray.length)];

$("#divId").css("color",randomColor); //A class selector would work too
```

Which would select a new color every time the page refreshes.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it.

The first part is a sequential order, element 1 gets color 1 etc.

Then when you are out of colors it will randomize it.

```
//Specify the class that you want to select
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-webpart-chrome-title");
var i;
var c;

//specify the colors you want to use
var colors = ["#009933", "#006699", "#33cccc", "#99cc00", "#f60"];
var d = colors.length;

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    while (i < d) {
        c = i;
        var random_color = colors[c];
        x[i].style.borderTopColor = random_color;
        i++;
    }
    while (i >= d) {
        var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        x[i].style.borderTopColor = random_color;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

without using predefined color set, to get a uniformly randomized color function

```
function randomColor(){
    rc = "#";
    for(i=0;i<6;i++){
        rc += Math.floor(Math.random()*16).toString(16);
    }
    return rc;
}
```

or inline

```
"#"+Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x1000000).toString(16)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attribute a bunch of colors to a list of items and make it look like they are picked at random, or if you just want to avoid using the same color all the time, you can use the nth-child with mod. For example:

```
li:nth-child(6n) {  background-color:  rgb(249, 195, 141);}
li:nth-child(6n+1) { background-color:  rgb(173, 255, 173);}
li:nth-child(6n+2) { background-color:  rgb(255, 255, 203);}
li:nth-child(6n+3) { background-color:  rgb(166, 197, 255);}
li:nth-child(6n+4) { background-color:  rgb(244, 197, 242);}
li:nth-child(6n+5) {  background-color:  rgb(255, 174, 178);}
```

Of course this is not a real mathematical random, but with enough colors compared to the number visible in the page, the reader will lose track, and have an impression close to randomness.

More info here: [nth-child with mod (or modulo) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127814/nth-child-with-mod-or-modulo-operator)