# CSS Nth-Child Checkered

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to use nth-child to change background colors of divs. Below is an image of how I want to change the background colors. How would I do this with nth-child?

[image]

Each box should be 25% width of it's parent container.

Answer (score 15):

Since it's a repeating pattern over 8 elements, you can use that to create the CSS:

```
div:nth-child(8n+1),
div:nth-child(8n+3),
div:nth-child(8n+6),
div:nth-child(8n) {
    background-color:black
}
div:nth-child(8n+2),
div:nth-child(8n+4),
div:nth-child(8n+5),
div:nth-child(8n+7) {
    background-color:gray
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RvbsL/2/

Comment: Exactly correct, this thought hit me and saw this posted before I could edit my answer.  Nice

Comment: You can remove the first line of CSS and apply the black background on all the divs, the nt-child() selector is more specific and will override the first css properties with the grey color. http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/A9Qs9/

Comment: For a responsive version (1 per line to 5 per line), check this css complete checkerboard example 
http://jsfiddle.net/Choufourax/pb09o5fa/1/

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**`:even`**](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html) and [**`:odd`**](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html), in this case:

```
div:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:grey;
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:black;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/RvbsL/)

Comment: What I'm trying to do though is float the divs so that they're are 25% width. The second row should swap the colors. See this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/RvbsL/1/

Answer (score 1):

This just doesn't appear to be possible - what you would need to do would be to use modulo to change the order in which the colors get applied depend on which row you're on, but you can only do addition or subtraction - explained here - [nth-child with mod (or modulo) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127814/nth-child-with-mod-or-modulo-operator)

Alternative solutions:

1. Wrap each "row" in a div so that you can select every other row
   separately to say gray should come first vs. black.
2. Use JS to loop through the elements where you can use modulus, and add a class to
   every other row and flip the way the background colors are applied.
3. Similar to 2, except just put the classes on the elements in the code before the page is loaded

EDIT:  Just realized I was totally wrong, you could do this since it's a repeating pattern every 8 divs instead of every 4.  Of course, before I could put a solution together, Andi beat me to the punch.  Touche - nice work!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the most elegant solution to your problem, but using div to group div in row, I was able to sort the odd and even row, and apply style to their odd or even child.

Take a look here : http://jsfiddle.net/3ASE8/

```
#div_parent {
    width: 500px;
}
.child {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #333;
    color: red;
}

.row:nth-child(odd) .child:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: #ccc!important;    
}
.row:nth-child(even) .child:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: #ccc!important;    
}
```

Comment: I just read that the width should be 25% instead of fixed px size.
I made the modification here: http://jsfiddle.net/3ASE8/1/