# Modulo css nth-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to find a way to display some colors to div following a pattern.

I found a trick using modulo but it doesn't seems to work with CSS...

So, as in the codepen example below:

- the blue background property should be apply on the 1,8,13,20,25... block
  -> We can see that the diff between each states are : 7 then 5 then 7 then 5 ...
- the green background property should be apply on the 4,9,16,21... block
  -> We can see that the diff between each states are : 5 then 7 then 5 then 7 ...
- the orange background property should be apply on the 5,12,17,24... block
  -> We can see that the diff between each states are : 7 then 5 then 7 then 5 ... ( just like the blue )

I tried using nth-child but I'm not really good in maths.
Any idea please?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjyaRB

```
 <div class="blue">blue</div>
  <div class="white">white</div>
  <div class="white">white</div>
  <div class="green">green</div>
  <div class="orange">orange</div>

  <div class="white">white</div>
  <div class="white">white</div>
  <div class="blue">blue</div>
  <div class="green">green</div>
  <div class="white">white</div>
  <div class="white">white</div>
  <div class="orange">orange</div>

  <div class="blue">blue</div>
  <div class="white">white</div>
  <div class="white">white</div>
  <div class="green">green</div>
  <div class="orange">orange</div>

  <div class="white">white</div>
  <div class="white">white</div>
  <div class="blue">blue</div>
  <div class="green">green</div>
  <div class="white">white</div>
  <div class="white">white</div>
  <div class="orange">orange</div>
```

Comment: In your example, the differences didn't converge (divergent sequences). Doing it with the position you gave us is easy, but the three dots suggest that the sequence continues.. So, what's the pattern to follow?

Comment: Actually if we detail the blue pattern :
1,8,13,20,25 ...
We can see that the diff between each states are : 7 then 5 then 7 then 5 ... 

That's the same thing for the orange

Furthermore, that's also pretty much the same for the green one :
4,9,16,21...
there is a diff between each states: 5 then 7 then 5 then 7 ...

Comment: Oh! I see... that's a good info to add to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127814/nth-child-with-mod-or-modulo-operator/6127837#6127837), `:nth-child()` does not support modulo operations. That said, this problem can still be solved using `:nth-child()`.

> We can see that the diff between each states are : 7 then 5 then 7 then 5 ...

The sum of 5 and 7 is 12. What you have, essentially, are two sequences with intervals of 12, just with slightly different starting points such that the difference between every two points alternates between 5 and 7. Here's a diagram to show you what I mean:

```
|---------------- 12 ----------------|--------------- 12 ----------------|
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
                     |-----------------12-----------------|
|--------- 7 --------|------ 5 ------|--------- 7 --------|------ 5 -----|
```

With this in mind, for the sequence that starts with 1 followed by 8, use `div:nth-child(12n+1)` and `div:nth-child(12n+8)`. The same follows with the other sequences.

Thus:

```css
div {
  height: 40px;
}

/* 1, 8, 13, 20, 25... */
div:nth-child(12n+1),
div:nth-child(12n+8) {
  background-color: blue;
}

/* 4, 9, 16, 21... */
div:nth-child(12n+4),
div:nth-child(12n+9) {
  background-color: green;
}

/* 5, 12, 17, 24... */
div:nth-child(12n+5),
/* Note: 12n+12, 12n+0, and 12n are all equivalent */
div:nth-child(12n+12) {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">blue</div>
<div class="white">white</div>
<div class="white">white</div>
<div class="green">green</div>
<div class="orange">orange</div>

<div class="white">white</div>
<div class="white">white</div>
<div class="blue">blue</div>
<div class="green">green</div>
<div class="white">white</div>
<div class="white">white</div>
<div class="orange">orange</div>

<div class="blue">blue</div>
<div class="white">white</div>
<div class="white">white</div>
<div class="green">green</div>
<div class="orange">orange</div>

<div class="white">white</div>
<div class="white">white</div>
<div class="blue">blue</div>
<div class="green">green</div>
<div class="white">white</div>
<div class="white">white</div>
<div class="orange">orange</div>
```

Comment: Quickly and well explained. +1 I will remove mine as it's basically the same.