# Repeat nth-child values

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to repeat a series of colours using nth-child??

In my example below I have set nth-children 1-4 with various colours now if I want to add the same repeat of colours from 4-8 can I do this with just css or will I need to use javascript??

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
}

.box:nth-child(4) {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

so the final output should have two rows of the same 4 colours

any help or tips would be appreciated!

**JAVASCRIPT**

Now I know I could create the elements in a loop and assign a class dynamically, but I'm wondering if there is a non js solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.box:nth-child(4n+x)` as your selector. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582228/modulo-css-nth-child) explains it well.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}

.box:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background: red;
}

.box:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background: blue;
}

.box:nth-child(4n+3) {
  background: yellow;
}

.box:nth-child(4n+4) {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

here's the solution. Instead of constant value use n parameter to do that.

> Here (4n+1) means that styling starts from the 1st child and repeats
>   it for the children that are multiple of 4. (4n+2) means that styling
>   starts from the 2nd child and repeats it for the children that are
>   multiple of 4.

Hope it will help you.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}

.box:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background: red;
}

.box:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background: blue;
}

.box:nth-child(4n+3) {
  background: yellow;
}

.box:nth-child(4n+4) {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```